# Position tooltip above mouse when room in viewport, otherwise below mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a tooltip and am having some problems with positioning it.

The tooltip is set to `position: absolute`, and I have a handler for mouse events that modifies it's `top` and `left` CSS depending on the `pageX` and `pageY`.

Now, I know I can just set the `top` to `pageY` and `left` to `pageX`.  That will make the tooltip pop up to the bottom-right.  I'm trying to orient it where it pops up on the top-right when there is room, but if it would be out of the viewport on the Y-axis, drop to the bottom-right position again.

At the moment, I'm stuck trying to get the tooltip to show to the top-right of the mouse.  I don't even know where to begin detecting if it would be in the viewport.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$('p').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $(tt).css('top', e.pageY - $(tt).css('height'));
    $(tt).css('left', e.pageX);
    $(tt).appendTo('body');
}).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $(tt).css('top', e.pageY - $(tt).css('height'));
    $(tt).css('left', e.pageX);    
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(tt).detach();
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5fzy9ez/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to handle tooltips, especially when using jQuery. This method probably would not have been my first choice. However, the following changes should work how you intended.

```
var tt = document.createElement('div');
tt.id = "tt";

$('p').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    var curPos = $( this ).offset().top - $( window ).scrollTop();
    var inView = (curPos < 250) ? 0 : 250;
    $(tt).css('top', e.pageY - inView);
    $(tt).css('left', e.pageX);
    $(tt).append($( this ).attr("data-myId"));
    $(tt).appendTo('body');
}).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $(tt).css('top', e.pageY - $(tt).css('height'));
    $(tt).css('left', e.pageX);    
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(tt).empty($( this ).attr("data-myId"));
    $(tt).detach();
});
```

[Full changes in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daw9jwuj/).

I am taking advantage of jQuery's `offset()` and `scrollTop()` methods to estimate the position of the current element within the viewable area of the document.

> According to jQuery's API documentation, the [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method
>   allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to
>   the document. The documentation also states that the vertical
>   scroll position ([`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)) is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden
>   from view above the scrollable area.

We use both of these methods to our advantage and subtract the number of pixels above the scrollable area from the current position of the element relative to the document. One important thing to note is that the offset method returns an object with the properties top and left.

```
var curPos = $( this ).offset().top - $( window ).scrollTop();
```

Since you had the #tt id set to a static 250px height, we can check if the current element position relative to the viewable portion of the window is less than 250. If it is, then we subtract nothing and let the tool tip sit below the mouse position. If it is greater than 250 then we subtract 250px and the tool tip will be above the current mouse position.

I am not sure how you were intending to pull in the content for the tool tips, but I also added `$(tt).append($( this ).attr("data-myId"));` to use the data-myId value as the tool tip content and `$(tt).empty($( this ).attr("data-myId"));` to clear it on `mouseleave`. I hope this helps!

Comment: If I could vote for your answer more than once, I would.  Yeah, I just put together a skeleton of what my actual code is to demonstrate the problem, which is why `data-myId` was there. What would have been your first choice?  Thanks!

Comment: Great! I am glad it was helpful. I tend to use only CSS on the rare occasions where I need to add them to a page, but I like what you are doing to keep the tool tip within the viewport.

Comment: Oh, I see.  For a normal tooltip, I would settle for CSS also.  This one mimics an item tooltip from a popular MMORPG, and it can get quite large / complicated when dynamically generated, which is why I was looking to do this.  Thanks again :)